# Dart: Wait all StreamSubscription async onData event functions to complete

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this specific code:

```
Stream<MimeMultipart> mm =
    MimeMultipartTransformer(boundary).bind(Stream.fromIterable(l));

// Completer. So we can wait for the two response results.
Completer<dynamic> allComplete = Completer<dynamic>();
List<Future> myAsyncs = [];
myAsyncs.add(allComplete.future);
int listenCalledCount = 0;

mm.listen((event) async {
  // this listen event executes multiple times...
  Completer<dynamic> listenEventCompleted = Completer<dynamic>();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10));
  print("Listening!!");
  myAsyncs.add(listenEventCompleted.future);
  listenCalledCount++; // How many times onData is called..
}, onDone: () => allComplete.complete(true));

await Future.wait(myAsyncs);
// I want all listen function called to be done first before continuing to the code below..
print(listenCalledCount);

print("All Done!");
```

My expected results are:

```
flutter: 3
flutter: All Done!
```

But what currently happening is:

```
flutter: 0
flutter: All Done!
```

What it means is, it doesn't  wait for the `StreamSubscription OnData event functions` which is `executed more than once` to complete. I want all the `OnData event` functions to complete before proceeding. Is this possible?

Comment: this is beacuse when you call `await Future.wait(myAsyncs);` the length of `myAsyncs` is 1

Comment: btw, why dont you use [await for (final value in stream) {](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#receiving-stream-events)?

Comment: because i want it to continue even an error occured until the end of stream because I use `multiparttransformer` stream

Comment: so handle those errors with `Stream.handleError`

Comment: something like: `void main() {
foo().then((_) => print('voila!!!'));
}

foo() async {
print('start!!!');
final stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), comp)
.handleError(handleError)
.take(8);
await for (final i in stream) {
print('i: $i');
}
print('done!!!');
}

handleError(error) {
print('>>>> error: $error');
}

int comp(i) {
if (i % 4 == 3) throw 'oops $i';
return i;
}`

Comment: Hi! I tested your answer. And it already achieved what I have in mind. Do you mind posting it as an answer so I can upvote it and mark it as the best answer? Thanks.

Comment: feel free to post a self answer then ;-)